# Add app with urls in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an app developed with angular 4 with simple url structure like localhost:4200/chat for chat page, now I want to add 'app' in url like localhost:4200/app/chat.

I want to change the url for some pages only but not for whole app.

I tried it with app routing file and menu items ts file but its not working and it stops workings instead.

is there any way to do this

Comment: Not sure if you want to add it to all routes, but if you want that, you can change the base href in your index file: `<base href="/app">`, this will append `app` on all routes.

Comment: Yes adding to all routes is an easy task but I want to change it for some of the pages ( components ), I have already build the app and if I go to change component directory structure just to change url it would be a time taking process and may cause app crash. There should be a work around to change it I believe but didnt find it yet.

Answer (score 1):

In your app.module.ts make sure your imports lists RouterModule.forRoot(routes), then in routes.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
 { 
   path: '/app',
   component: 'AppComponent'
 },
 { 
   path: '',
   redirectTo: '/app',
   pathMatch: 'full'
 }
];
```

Read the [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router) documentation for more info.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I already have this to redirect app to a common page but here I want to change the url of existing component like chat , right now its url is localhost:4200/chat and I want to change it to localhost:4200/app/chat and there are other urls I want to change.

Comment: Maybe I’m misunderstanding, I’m a fairly new programmer, but don’t you just change and add the paths you need in your router file? Can you post some sample code to demonstrate what you’re trying to do?